# How to write UInt8Array buffer to media file format from browser?

Tags: javascript, file-io, binary-data, typed-arrays

In my javascript code running in browser, I have parsed a video into separate audio and video stream buffers. Both audio and video frames are in form of UInt8Array buffer and I want to write it to disk in .aac/.mp4 or another media format file, which should be playable by VLC or other media players. I found some answers on stackoverflow which are about writing typed-array to binary format file on disk, but the file I need to save is proper media files. How do I write a TypedArray in memory to a audio/video files on disk in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

```
function download(text, name) {


    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var buf = str2ab(text);
    var fileNew = new Blob([buf], {
        type: "image/jpeg"
    });
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(fileNew);
    a.download = name;
    a.click();

}

function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length);
  var bufView = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return buf;
}
```